# How to make Identity Server forget credentials - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, identityserver4, logout

I have a WPF application and am using Identity Server 4 for authentication. I log in using a WpfEmbeddedBrowser class. The issue is whenever I click the "remember me" checkbox on the login page, the user gets automatically logged in every time. This is fine, but I can't figure out how to make it stop when the user clicks a log out button. How do I log the user out on Identity Server 4 and WPF?

Here is my WpfEmbeddedBrowser:

```
public class WpfEmbeddedBrowser : IBrowser
    {
        private BrowserOptions _options = null;

        public WpfEmbeddedBrowser()
        {

        }

        public async Task<BrowserResult> InvokeAsync(BrowserOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            _options = options;

            var window = new Window()
            {
                Width = 450,
                Height = 750,
                Title = "SiteMonitor Desktop Application Login"
            };

            var webBrowser = new WebBrowser();

            var signal = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);
            window.Show();
            var result = new BrowserResult()
            {
                ResultType = BrowserResultType.UserCancel
            };

            webBrowser.Navigating += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (BrowserIsNavigatingToRedirectUri(e.Uri))
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;

                    result = new BrowserResult()
                    {
                        ResultType = BrowserResultType.Success,
                        Response = e.Uri.AbsoluteUri
                    };

                    signal.Release();

                    window.Close();
                }
            };

            window.Closing += (s, e) =>
            {
                signal.Release();
            };

            window.Content = webBrowser;
            window.Show();
            webBrowser.Source = new Uri(_options.StartUrl);

            await signal.WaitAsync();

            return result;
        }

        private bool BrowserIsNavigatingToRedirectUri(Uri uri)
        {
            return uri.AbsoluteUri.StartsWith(_options.EndUrl);
        }
    }
```

Here is where I call WpfEmbeddedBrowser:

```
//prompt login
            var options = new OidcClientOptions()
            {
                Authority = Current.Properties["IdentityServerAPIAddress"].ToString(),
                ClientId = "wpf",
                ClientSecret = "secret",
                Scope = "openid offline_access WebAPI",
                RedirectUri = "http://localhost/signin-oidc",
                Flow = OidcClientOptions.AuthenticationFlow.AuthorizationCode,
                Browser = new WpfEmbeddedBrowser()
            };

            _oidcClient = new OidcClient(options);

            try
            {
                result = await _oidcClient.LoginAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //if this is thrown, it's probably because the login page loaded before the API
                MessageBox.Show("IdenitityServerAPI probably loaded before WPF. Try restarting.");
                Current.Shutdown();
                return;
            }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On logout you need to call [Logout method of OidcClient](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient/blob/main/src/OidcClient/OidcClient.cs#L124). sth like this:

```
private async void LogoutButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await _oidcClient.LogoutAsync();
}
```